# Properly include CSS

Tags: html, css, django, dom, django-templates

I have one Django template (main page) which includes another template (navbar).
I have one CSS file for my main page, and one for my navbar.
My question is: how to properly include the CSS of the navbar in the main page ?

I tried this (1):

main_page.html

```
{% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
{% endblock %}
```

navbar.html

```
{% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css">
{% endblock %}
```

or just (2)

main_page.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

navbar.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css">
```

Then in main_page.html

```
{% include "base/navbar.html" %}
```

In each cases, both of the CSS are loaded (main_page + navbar), but I don't think that include CSS like this is good.
What is the proper way to include CSS among a HTML page with `include` of Django ?

In case (1), even if I use `{% block %}`, the CSS of the main_page is still kept, and not replaced with the CSS I specified in navbar.html. Is it a normal behavior (because usage of include instead of extends ?) ?

Thank you in advance,
Flo

Answer (score 2):

In order to extend a template block you need to include `{{ block.super }}` this will include what you declared in parent template:

```
{% block css %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css">
{% endblock %}
```

But a better solution is to use `sekizai` which is a library that lets you easily include assets: http://django-sekizai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

There are also more complex solutions that allow you to compress and group your assets:
http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I use `include` not `extends` to include my navbar in the middle of my page, so this slution doesn't work.
I try to include a CSS with my navbar, but don't know how to do it because the when I include the navbar, the `<head></head>` are already here. So I don't know how to put an additional `<link css...>` with `include` template statement.

Comment: `Sekizai` is very simple and fast.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to use include instead of extend? Because there might be a slight change you are not using the django template system as it has been intended to. Have you been a heavy PHP user before?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to include css(or js) in Django temple.
I will post what I use in my projects.

1. in any template that uses css/js
   exclusively in  them put them inside that template

like,

inside "main_page.html"

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

inside "navbar.html"

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css">`